# A battery and other things are connected to the two ends of a resistor. Is the voltage between the resistor's terminals exactly that of the battery?

Tags: circuit-analysis

For ex,

[image]

So see the 6V battery connected to the two ends of the 1k resistor. Now, is it try that the potential difference between the terminal of the RESISTOR equal to that of the battery? I mean there is also a currently source that might generate som counter-voltage to the battery.

By counter voltage, I mean like:

[image]

In this case, the battery is trying to make the current throught the resistor go down, whereas the current source is trying to make it go up. I know in picture 1, a current source isn't exactly this close to the battery, and not exactly in parallel with it, but for some reason, it may be have an effect like this.

Comment: Yes, the voltage is the same at the schematic level. However, this is only true if the wires connecting the resistor to battery have zero resistance. Real wires have some resistance, so there will be some voltage drop in the wires. If there are other power sources (like the current source in your circuit) then the battery may be under recharge. In this case, the voltage across the resistor could  be slightly higher than the battery voltage.

Comment: The other thing worth mentioning is that real batteries have an effective series resistance. So when you connect a load to a battery, the external voltage drops more or less instantly in response to the load current. After the initial jump, it will then decline slowly according to its normal discharge curve. If you connect a charger, the external battery voltage jumps up more or less instantly due to the charge current. It will then climb slowly according to its normal charge curve.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already, in an ideal circuit which I believe your is, the voltage across the resistor is the same as that of the 6V battery across the resistor. That voltage is fixed by the battery.

Comment: why no counter voltage

Comment: @user132522 What do you mean by "counter voltage"

Comment: I mean battery is not the only thing connection to the terminal, can there be other voltage that works again the battery?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the battery is a perfect 6v voltage source, and the 1k is connected directly to it by wires of negligible resistance (what's shown in the schematic) then the voltage across the 1k resistor will be exactly 6v.

If you assume that the 6v source is modelled more like a real battery, with internal resistance, and a voltage that varies with temperature and charge state, then the voltage won't be exactly 6v. However, you should show that complication on the diagram, otherwise how would anybody be able to compute it? If the connecting wires have resistance, that too should be shown, if you want to take it into account.